# How to make one method return different values for user with role ADMIN and USER?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I need to make the `@Get` method, and for users with `ROLE_USER` it should return other values than for users with `ROLE_ADMIN`.

The URL have to be the same.

How to do it with Spring Security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your authentification passed well you could just inject [@AuthenticationPrincipal](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/core/annotation/AuthenticationPrincipal.html):

```
@GetMapping("/get-url-here")
public String main(@AuthenticationPrincipal User user) {
    if (user.getRole().equals("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        // set values for admin
    } else {
        // set for user
    }
    return "view-or-response-body";
}
```

I assume that you have the `User` class configured, like:

```
public class User {
    public String role;
    // other fields, getters, setters
}
```

Or `role` could be enum as well.

Comment: User might have few roles so Role is another class there Is many to many relationship between Role and User

Answer (score -1):

Question is not 100% clear, but what I would do is make an Enum field in the user class (assuming that class exists) for the role and return the value of that field when the URL is called.

Comment: I am using spring boot security